# Cannot set the border of horizonal rule to be dotted in presence of Bootstrap 5 link

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make the horizontal rule to be have border-style dotted on my site. But for some reason, it doesn't happen as long as there is bootstrap-5 cdn embedded. I also tried it on codeply and it works fine until I add the Bootstrap-5 Framework, at which point the border-style reverts back to normal. Here is the CSS I'm applying on the horizontal rule which has the class "horizontal-rule".

```
.horizontal-rule{
           width: 5%;
           border-style: dotted none none;
           border-width: 7px;
           }
```

Could someone enlighten me as to why this is happening and how I can solve this?

Comment: not able to repro:  https://codeply.com/p/wGRJI6udKM

Comment: Same problem here. Solved it by being more specific when selecting the element. Define and id for ur element and style it then by selecting the id.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap likely has its own styling for `<hr>` you'll need to open something like Developer tools to see what CSS you need to add to your declarations to **override** what Bootstrap defines in order for your styles to work.

Also, make sure that you're including your custom CSS **After** the bootstrap CSS so that your rules take precedence.